# How can I test my pre-receive hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I need to create a pre-receive hook that rejects push from any client from any branch which is not master, So I wrote this script:

```
     #!/bin/bash

    refname="$0"
    oldrev="$1"
    newrev="$2"

    alowed_branch='master'
    current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

    if [ $alowed_branch = $current_branch ]
    then
      echo "you are pushing to master branch"
      exit 0
    else
      echo Branch $current_branch is Locked.
     exit 1
    fi
```

Now I don't know how can I test it...

When tested on a 'pre-commit' hook on my local git repo I get what I want:

[image]

But when trying to test it as a pre-push or pre-receive hook as suggested it doesn't take any effect and I can commit and push with no interference.

is there a way to test it on GitHub?

Comment: Try to push to a remote branch that is not master.  If your hook works then you are fine, and if it doesn't work you can just delete the remote branch and try again.

Comment: I pushed it to the remote branch, but I tested it as a pre-commit hook, Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: It seems that `pre-push` or `pre-receive` would be a better idea.

Comment: @Opal  when trying pre-push or pre-receive it does not take effect  on my local repo

Comment: Seems bug here. `current_branch=$(refname)`. Your code is trying to run **refname** command in subshell. I think `current_branch=${refname}` is what you want.

Comment: ok,
Fixed the script and gave executable permissions to the post-push script and now it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing hooks, especially pre-receive hooks, is difficult: they run in unusual environments.  There are few good ways to test them (the main good way is a sacrificial repository or two).

You have a number of intertwining problems here:

> ```
> refname="$0"
> ```

This is just wrong no matter what, as in a shell script, `$0` refers to the *name of the script itself*.

> ```
> current_branch=$(refname)
> ```

This, which you deleted in an edit, was also wrong: it tries to run the command `refname`.  So it's good that you replaced it, but:

> ```
> current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
> ```

This is subtly wrong: if your current branch is named `fixes/bug-123` it will set `current_branch` to `bug-123`, not `fixes/bug-123`.

To get the *current branch name* as a symbolic reference minus the `refs/heads/` part, use:

```
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || exit 1
```

The `--short` directs `git symbolic-ref` to omit the `refs/heads/` part, and the `|| exit 1` directs the *shell* to exit (with failure status) if `git symbolic-ref` itself fails, which it could: if you have a "detached HEAD", `HEAD` is *not* a symbolic ref, and Git will complain about that and `current_branch` will be set to the empty string.

Now, with those out of the way, you mention:

> ... trying to test it as a pre-push or pre-receive hook ...

As a pre-push hook, `$1` and `$2` (which you store in `oldrev` and `newrev`) would actually be set to the name and URL of the remote!  The old and new revision IDs, and the old and new reference names, are passed to that hook as its *standard input*.  This all happens on the client side, after connecting to the other Git (the remote) but before sending anything.  [(See the section on `pre-push` hooks in the githooks documentation.)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_pre_push)

As a pre-receive hook, `$1` and `$2` would *not be set to anything at all* (which is OK since you never use the variables anyway).  The *current branch* would be the current branch *in the other Git on the remote*.  A pre-receive hook, like a pre-push hook, must *read its standard input*, one line at a time, checking each group of parameters supplied on that line.  If the hook exits with a nonzero return, the entire push is rejected (from the server's side).

When checking reference names in a pre-push or pre-receive hook, be sure to check the *entire* reference: an incoming reference (in either hook) or outgoing reference (in a pre-push hook) can refer to a tag, for instance, as in `refs/tags/v1.2`, or a branch whose name includes slashes, as in `refs/heads/feature/tall`.  Don't just chop off all but the last part of the name, nor the first two components without looking at them.  And, in either hook, the current branch name is normally entirely irrelevant: someone running `git push` specifies *which reference(s) to push* on the command line:

```
git push origin \
  refs/heads/master:refs/for/master \
  refs/tags/v1.2:refs/tags/v1.2 \
  refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits \
  refs/peculiar-ref:refs/even-stranger/master
```

for instance.  None of these is going into a *branch* on the target; only one is *from* a branch on the source.

(Note that hooks can be written in any language that can run on the machine on which that particular Git is installed.  They don't *have* to be bash / sh scripts—though if you have Git you must have a shell, since parts of Git are written in shell.  Always beware of hardcoded paths: for instance, bash may be located in `/usr/local/bin/bash` rather than `/bin/bash` on some systems.)